# Multiple bullets not showing up when added to Pygame sprite group and updated

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on my first project in Python / Pygame, which is a shooter-style game. However, when I create multiple instances of  my Bullet sprite and add them to the sprite group, only the most recent instance is shown on the screen. That is, only one bullet is showing at any given time.

I think Lines 175-180 or within the Bullet class are causing the problem.

My code:

```
import pygame, random , sys , time
from pygame.locals import *

# Screen dimensions
SCREEN_WIDTH = 640
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480

# Global constants
WHITE     = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK     = (  0,   0,   0)
LIGHTBLUE = (  0,   0, 155)
FPS = 60

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # set speed vector of the player
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0
    moverate = 5
    # Constructor. Pass in x and y position
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Create player image
        self.image = pygame.image.load('player.png')
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        # Set a referance to the image rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        """ Change the speed of the player"""
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def update(self):
        """ Move the player. """

        # Move left/right

        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        # Move up/down
        self.rect.y += self.change_y


    def stop(self):
        """ Called when the user lets off the keyboard."""
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.image = pygame.image.load('player.png')
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the enemy sprites."""
    minmoverate = 1
    maxmoverate = 8

    def __init__(self):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('enemyShip.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (50, 50))
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def reset_pos(self):
        """ Reset position to the top of the screen, at a random x location.
        Called by update() or the main program loop if there is a collision."""

        self.rect.y = - ( SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4)
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)


    def update(self):
        """ Move the enemies. """
        # Move down, at some speed
        self.rect.y += 2
        # Move left and right, at some speed
        self.rect.x += 0

        # If enemy is too far down, reset to top of screen
        if self.rect.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.reset_pos()



class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the bullet. """
    def __init__(self):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([8, 20])
        self.image.fill(LIGHTBLUE)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        """ Move the bullet. """
        self.rect.y -= 10

class Game(object):
    """ This class represents an instance of the game. If we need to
        rest the game we'd just need to create a new instance of this class."""

    # --- Class attributes.

    # Sprite lists
    enemy_list = None
    bullet_list = None
    all_sprites_list = None


    # --- Class methods
    # Set up the game
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.game_over = False

        # Create sprite lists
        self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

        # Create the starting enemy ships
        for i in range(15):
            enemy = Enemy()

            enemy.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)
            enemy.rect.y = random.randrange(-300, 20)

            self.enemy_list.add(enemy)
            self.all_sprites_list.add(enemy)

        # Create the player
        self.player = Player(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT - (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 6))
        self.all_sprites_list.add(self.player)


    def process_events(self):
        """ Process all of the events. Return "True" if we need to close the window."""

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return True

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    return True
                elif event.key == K_RETURN:
                    if self.game_over:
                        self.__init__()
                elif event.key in (K_RIGHT ,K_d):
                    self.player.changespeed( self.moverate ,0)
                elif event.key in (K_LEFT ,K_a):
                    self.player.changespeed( -self.moverate ,0)
                elif event.key in (K_UP , K_w):
                    self.player.changespeed(0, -self.moverate)
                elif event.key in (K_DOWN , K_s):
                    self.player.changespeed(0, self.moverate)
                elif event.key == K_SPACE: # Fire bullet
                    bullet = Bullet(0
                    # Set bullet so it is where the player is
                    bullet.rect.centerx = self.player.rect.centerx 
                    bullet.rect.y = self.player.rect.y

                    # Add bullet to lists
                    self.all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                    self.bullet_list.add(bullet)

            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key in (K_RIGHT ,K_d):
                    self.player.changespeed( -self.moverate ,0)
                elif event.key in (K_LEFT ,K_a):
                    self.player.changespeed( self.moverate ,0)
                elif event.key in (K_UP , K_w):
                    self.player.changespeed(0, self.moverate)
                elif event.key in (K_DOWN , K_s):
                    self.player.changespeed(0, -self.moverate)



    def run_logic(self):
        """ This method is run each time through the frame.
            It updates positions and checks for collisions."""
        enemy = Enemy()
        if not self.game_over:
            # Move all the sprites
            self.all_sprites_list.update()

            if len(self.all_sprites_list) < 17:
                self.enemy_list.add(enemy)
                self.all_sprites_list.add(enemy)
                enemy.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)
                enemy.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -50)

            # Bullet Mechanics
            for bullet in self.bullet_list:
                # See if the bullets has collided with anything.
                self.enemy_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, self.enemy_list, True)

                # For each enemy hit, remove bullet and enemy and add to score
                for enemy in self.enemy_hit_list: 
                    self.bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                    self.all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
                    self.score += 1

                # Remove the bullet if it flies up off the screen
                if bullet.rect.y < -10:
                    self.bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                    self.all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

            # Player Mechanics
            for enemy in self.enemy_list:
                # See if player has collided with anything.
                self.player_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.enemy_list, True)

                if len(self.player_hit_list) == 1:
                    # If player is hit, show game over.
                    self.game_over = True

    def display_frame(self, screen):
        """ Display everything to the screen for the game. """
        screen.fill(BLACK)

        if self.game_over:
            # font = pygame.font.Font("Serif:, 25)
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("serif", 25)
            text = font.render("Game Over! You scored " + str(self.score) +" points, press Enter to restart", True, WHITE)
            center_x = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2) - (text.get_width() // 2)
            center_y = (SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2) - (text.get_height() // 2)
            screen.blit(text, [center_x, center_y])

        if not self.game_over:
            self.all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

def main():
    """ Main program function. """
    # Initialize Pygame and set up the window
    pygame.init()

    size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    # Create our objects and set the data
    done = False
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # Create an instance of the Game class
    game = Game()

    # Main game loop
    while not done:

        # Process events (keystrokes, mouse clicks, etc)
        done = game.process_events()

        # Update object positions, check for collisions
        game.run_logic()

        # Draw the current frame
        game.display_frame(screen)

        # Pause for the next frame
        clock.tick(FPS)

    # Close window and exit
    pygame.quit()

# Call the main function, start up the game
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're only ever creating a single `Bullet` instance, which you're storing in the `Game.bullet` class variable. Whenever you shoot, the code moves that single bullet to the player's position, and it updates from there.

You probably want to create a new bullet for every shot. Use something like this in `process_events`:

```
            elif event.key == K_SPACE: # Fire bullet
                bullet = Bullet()
                bullet.rect.centerx = self.player.rect.centerx 
                bullet.rect.y = self.player.rect.y

                # Add bullet to lists
                all_sprites_list.add(self.bullet)
                bullet_list.add(self.bullet)
```

That creates a new bullet every time the space bar is pressed. If your game design specifies a limit to the number of bullets that can be "active" at once, you may need some more complex logic (or if the performance cost of creating and destroying lots of instances is too much you could write some object caching code), but this should get you on the right track.

Now, the code above doesn't do anything to remove the bullets later, so you'll probably need to handle that too or your game will bog down from the calculations involving off-screen bullets. I'd suggest putting some logic in `Bullet.update()` that calls `self.kill()` if the bullet is off the screen (or whenever makes sense  for your game). The instance will be garbage collected automatically when there are no more references to it.

I'd also suggest getting rid of all of the class variables of you `Game` class, which are either unnecessary (they get shadowed by instance variables that are created in `__init__`), or broken (like `bullet`).

Comment: When I first made that process, that's where I originally called the Bullet class, but it gave an error that my '"Game" object has no attribute 'bullet'', which I tried to fix by creating a class variable... so I'm kind of stuck on how to create an instance in that method without creating a class variable for bullet.

Comment: I don't see anything in the current code that would give that error, as long as you change all the `self.bullet` references to just `bullet` as I did above. If you try it and still get that error, please edit the full traceback into your question.

Comment: Ah, I didn't change all the self.bullet references. As for handling off-screen bullets, would it be better to put in in Bullet.update() or thrown in the run_logic method as I have currently?

Comment: I think it would be pretty easy to do in `Bullet.update`. Try putting `if self.rect.y < -self.rect.height: self.kill()` just below the spot you update `self.rect.y` (I'm assuming `y=0` is the top of the screen).